# How do I split a string into separate lists?

Tags: python, split

I am given this as a string:

```
Orville Wright 21 July 1988 \n
Rogelio Holloway 13 September 1988 \n
Marjorie Figueroa 9 October 1988 \n
```

I need to separate the names from the dates and print it like this:

```
Birthdate:
21 July 1988 \n
13 September 1988 \n
9 October 1988 \n
etc..
```

I tried to save the string into a variable and split it into a list

```py
content = ""

temp = content.strip()
temp = temp.split()
```

Comment: You could use split with a regex pattern to act on the first numerical digit and on the newline.

Answer (score 1):

You can use regex for this problem:

```
import re
str = 'Orville Wright 21 July 1988 \n Rogelio Holloway 13 September 1988 \n Marjorie Figueroa 9 October 1988 \n'
Birthdate = re.findall(r'(\d+ \w+ \d+)', str)
>>> ['21 July 1988', '13 September 1988', '9 October 1988']
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming this is how the content will be

```
content = 'Orville Wright 21 July 1988 \n Rogelio Holloway 13 September 1988 \n Marjorie Figueroa 9 October 1988 \n'
```

and then we do

```
content = content.strip().split('\n')

BirthDate = ''

for a in aa:
    a = a.strip().split(' ')
    date = f'{a[2]} {a[3]} {a[4]} \n '
    BirthDate = BirthDate + date
```

Comment: This is vanilla method